Can't remove old role from brew install
I'm trying to completely uninstall and then reinstall a clean version of postgresql via homebrew.
Following various SO and other guides I've run the following commands to clear out the existing version of postgresql:
brew uninstall postgresql
rm -f ~/.psqlrc ~/.psql_history
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14
rm /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log

I then reinstall via:
brew install postgresql
brew services start postgresql
createuser -s postgres

I then log in via:
psql -h localhost -U postgres

However, when I get a list of roles via \du I get the following result:
                                    List of roles
 Role name  |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 <old_role> | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 postgres   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}


What am I missing in my uninstall/reinstall that this old role keeps cropping back up?

Edit:
Found one other folder that looked related to postgresql but it looked to be cleared out by one of the other removal statements. For belt and braces I removed that too:
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14


Edit 2:
Found a bunch more folders and files that looked worthy of removal including a an older v17 install that I'd attempted previously:
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libpq

rm /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/locks/postgresql@14.formula.lock
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql@14--14.15
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql@14_bottle_manifest--14.15
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/bc00610f0dd0a86769cdf60cd572359a0c1a17618a39d0f8f37b247d69da1508--postgresql@14--14.15.arm64_sequoia.bottle.tar.gz
rm -rf /Users/<username>/Library/Logs/Homebrew/postgresql@14

rm /opt/homebrew/bin/psql-17
rm /opt/homebrew/bin/postgres-17
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/include/postgresql@17
rm /opt/homebrew/var/homebrew/locks/postgresql@17.formula.lock
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/postgresql@17
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql@17--17.2
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/f741434e9fddc146750d1ff0671ebf679e30e9a7b3d91b3141fa31c74b9a3ae6--postgresql@17--17.2.arm64_sequoia.bottle.tar.gz
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/032ded11eab504174b5d4db6d07ec24a6c811e09d0f4e64854cad9f5c7bfe674--postgresql@17-17.2.bottle_manifest.json
rm /Users/<username>/Library/Caches/Homebrew/postgresql@17_bottle_manifest--17.2
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/lib/postgresql@17
rm -rf /Users/<username>/Library/Logs/Homebrew/postgresql@17

Still no luck - old role is still there!!!

Run type psql to see what you are actually running. Whatever that tells you, run ls -l on it to see what it is linked to.

Roles are global to a cluster, so either you still have old cluster of Postgres running that you are connecting to or you are bringing the roles in from a dump file.

@MarkSetchell - type psql returns psql is /opt/homebrew/bin/psql. That is an alias to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.15/bin/psql

@AdrianKlaver - definitely not using or have ever used dump files. How would I find an old cluster of Postgres? I was sure it was the v17 install that was causing the issues but I'm pretty sure I've deleted all of that - see "Edit 2" of my post

In psql what does select version(); return? In terminal what does ps ax | grep postgres return?

@AdrianKlaver - i) PostgreSQL 14.15 (Homebrew) on aarch64-apple-darwin24.1.0, compiled by Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4), 64-bit and ii) returns quite a few lines referencing 127.0.0.1 and some other misc stuff - the only file path is this one: /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14

Is <old_role> the same name as the user you are installing Postgres as? If so the from here Homebrew: It will give you instructions on creating an initial database. When you do it will be "owned" by your username and create the postgres and template1 databases.

@AdrianKlaver - is it indeed!!! Thanks a million for clearing this up!
